# rar.exe does not compress specified extension and subdirectories

Tags: windows, command-line, rar, winrar

I am developing a C# app which in some phase uses the `rar.exe` to compress some `PDB` files.

I would like the `rar.exe` to compress **only** the `PDB` files which are located in some directory and in its **subdirectories**.

The problem is that it compresses **all the files** (even not `PDB`s) that are in that directory and also compresses directories which are **parents** of the directory I specified - which is not what i want it to do.

This is the command line I am using right now:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -r -ep1 C:\Users\bla\Desktop\VersionTest\3.5.x\2.0\x64\Release\PDB\PDBs.rar *.pdb C:\Users\bla\Desktop\output64
```

Does any one know why my command line doesn't provide what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The manual for the console version `Rar.exe` of *WinRAR* is the text file `Rar.txt` in the program files folder of *WinRAR*. It describes the general syntax, the RAR commands and the switches which can be used with `Rar.exe` and the exit values.

How is the command line below interpreted by `Rar.exe`?

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -r C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\VersionTest\3.5.x\2.0\x64\Release\PDB\PDBs.rar *.pdb C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\output64
```

1. The RAR command is `a`. So there should be files/folders **added** to a RAR archive file which must be created on not already existing.
2. The switch `-ep1` instructs `Rar.exe` in **excluding paths** from all **specified** files/folders up to last backslash.
3. The switch `-r` instructs `Rar.exe` in not only archiving the specified files/folders, but also all other files and folders found **recursively** matching the wildcard pattern in the specified folders.
4. `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\VersionTest\3.5.x\2.0\x64\Release\PDB\PDBs.rar` is the fully qualified archive file name.
5. `*.pdb` instructs `Rar.exe` in archiving all files (and folders) of which log name ends case-insensitive with `.pdb` found in the current directory (no path) and in all subdirectories of the current directory because of the switch `-r` without adding the path to current directory also to the archive file.
6. `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\output64` instructs `Rar.exe` in archiving all files/folders in the folder `C:\Users\bla\Desktop\output64` and in all subdirectories of this directory because of the switch `-r` without adding the path `C:\Users\bla\Desktop\` also to the archive file because of the switch `-ep1`. The wildcard pattern used implicitly in this case is `*` for all files and folders.

But added to the archive file should be just the **files** matching the wildcard pattern `*.pdb` in the directory `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\output64` and its subdirectories. For this purpose is needed the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -ed -r C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\VersionTest\3.5.x\2.0\x64\Release\PDB\PDBs.rar C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\output64\*.pdb
```

The arguments instruct `Rar.exe` to

1. search in directory `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\output64` and **recursively** in all its subdirectories because of the switch `-r`
2. for only **files** matching the wildcard pattern `*.pdb` because of the switch `-ed` to **exclude** file system entries with attribute **directory**
3. and **exclude** because of the switch `-ep1` the **specified path** `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\output64\` from each fully qualified file name of each file
4. to **add** to the archive file `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\VersionTest\3.5.x\2.0\x64\Release\PDB\PDBs.rar`.